# seam with tomcat "entityManager is null"

Tags: seam, tomcat7

I have a problem when deploying seam with tomcat. I get this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: entityManager is null
    at org.jboss.seam.framework.EntityQuery.validate(EntityQuery.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)

.......................................
```

Here are my details. I have followed all the details from jboss seam jpa example :

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" 
             version="1.0">
   <persistence-unit name="bookingDatabase">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/TestDB</non-jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider"/>
         
         
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is my component.xml. I think there is no problem with it.

components.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<components xmlns="http://jboss.com/products/seam/components"
            xmlns:core="http://jboss.com/products/seam/core"
            xmlns:persistence="http://jboss.com/products/seam/persistence"
            xmlns:drools="http://jboss.com/products/seam/drools"
            xmlns:bpm="http://jboss.com/products/seam/bpm"
            xmlns:security="http://jboss.com/products/seam/security"
            xmlns:mail="http://jboss.com/products/seam/mail"
            xmlns:web="http://jboss.com/products/seam/web"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:cache="http://jboss.com/products/seam/cache"
            xmlns:async="http://jboss.com/products/seam/async"
            xmlns:transaction="http://jboss.com/products/seam/transaction"
            
            xsi:schemaLocation=
                    "http://jboss.com/products/seam/core http://jboss.com/products/seam/core-2.2.xsd
                 http://jboss.com/products/seam/persistence http://jboss.com/products/seam/persistence-2.2.xsd
                 http://jboss.com/products/seam/drools http://jboss.com/products/seam/drools-2.2.xsd
                 http://jboss.com/products/seam/bpm http://jboss.com/products/seam/bpm-2.2.xsd
                 http://jboss.com/products/seam/security http://jboss.com/products/seam/security-2.2.xsd
                 http://jboss.com/products/seam/mail http://jboss.com/products/seam/mail-2.2.xsd
                 http://jboss.com/products/seam/web http://jboss.com/products/seam/web-2.2.xsd
                 http://jboss.com/products/seam/cache http://jboss.com/products/seam/cache-2.2.xsd
                 http://jboss.com/products/seam/transaction http://jboss.com/products/seam/transaction-2.2.xsd
                 http://jboss.com/products/seam/components http://jboss.com/products/seam/components-2.2.xsd
                 http://jboss.com/products/seam/async http://jboss.com/products/seam/async-2.0.xsd ">

     
      
    <core:manager concurrent-request-timeout="500"
                  conversation-timeout="120000"
                  conversation-id-parameter="cid"
                  parent-conversation-id-parameter="pid"/>
                  
    <transaction:entity-transaction entity-manager="#{em}"/>
                  
    <persistence:entity-manager-factory name="bookingDatabase"/>
    
    <persistence:managed-persistence-context name="em"
                               auto-create="true" 
                    entity-manager-factory="#{bookingDatabase}"/>
                    
    <security:identity authenticate-method="#{authenticator.authenticate}"/>  
    
    <async:quartz-dispatcher/>
    
    <cache:eh-cache-provider name="cacheProvider" auto-create="true"/>
    


    <!-- Make sure this URL pattern is the same as that used by the Faces Servlet -->
    <web:hot-deploy-filter url-pattern="*.seam"/>

    <drools:rule-base name="securityRules">
        <drools:rule-files>
            <value>/security.drl</value>
        </drools:rule-files>
    </drools:rule-base>

    <security:rule-based-permission-resolver security-rules="#{securityRules}"/>

    <security:jpa-identity-store
            user-class="org.domain.simpopanpa.entity.UserAccount"
            role-class="org.domain.simpopanpa.entity.UserRole"/>

    <security:jpa-permission-store
            user-permission-class="org.domain.simpopanpa.entity.UserPermission"/>



    <event type="org.jboss.seam.security.notLoggedIn">
        <action execute="#{redirect.captureCurrentView}"/>
    </event>
    <event type="org.jboss.seam.security.loginSuccessful">
        <action execute="#{redirect.returnToCapturedView}"/>
    </event>

    <mail:mail-session host="localhost" port="25"/>

    


   
</components>
```

I have added the context.xml file as described in some forums.
context.xml

```
<Context path="/someName" docBase="someName"
        debug="5" reloadable="true" crossContext="true">

    <Resource auth="Container"
      name="jdbc/TestDB"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
      url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:db11g"
      username="user"
      password="pass"
      maxActive="100"
      maxIdle="30"
      maxWait="10000"/>
 
</Context>
```

I use tomcat 7 and jboss seam 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

You named the persistence context 'em'. The entityquery is per default trying to fetch it by 'entitymanager'. So either change the name in your components.xml or you have to call entityquery.setPersistenceContextName("em").